# Calculating maximum product of the results of calling many functions with the same argument

Tags: function, functional-programming, j

I have this code:

```
f1 =: some function that returns list of numbers
f2 =: some function that returns list of numbers
f3 =: some function that returns list of numbers
f4 =: some function that returns list of numbers
max_mult_all =: (*/f1) >. (*/f2) >. (*/f3) >. (*/f4)
```

Is there any better way to initialize `max_mult_all`? What if I have hundreds of these functions? Is it possible to use Insert(`/`) style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you first box each function you can `*/` each list and then `>./` on the results:

```
>./ ; */ each (f1;f2;f3;f4) y
```

Moreover, if the functions have the same shape and size you can put them in a gerund

```
F =: f1`f2`f3`f4
```

from which you build a matrix of the results

```
M =: F `:0 ] y
```

and then perform your calculations on the matrix

```
>./*/"1 M
```

Comment: using `every` instead of `each` then means you don't need to use `;`. i.e. `>./ */ every (f1;f2;f3;f4) y`

Comment: @Tikkanz, indeed, using `every` here is more appropriate.